# bash_profile and the PATH variable

Tags: path, environment-variables, bash

I have the following in my bash_profile to automatically run the `smlnj`interpreter:

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/smlnj-110.74/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

Additionally I would also like to run the`swi prolog` interpreter by adding its path at:

```
\opt\local\bin
```

How can I set the `PATH` variable to check both or is there a better way?

Why does [Petite Chez Scheme](http://www.scheme.com/petitechezscheme.html) require no `PATH` or environment variable settings? That is, when I type `petite` into the terminal the petite chez scheme interpreter starts automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I set the PATH variable to check both?

This is one way, not necessarily the best way

```sh
items=(
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin
  /usr/local/smlnj-110.74/bin
  /opt/local/bin
)
for item in ${items[*]}
do
  PATH=${item}:${PATH}
done
export PATH
```

> Why does Petite Chez Scheme require no PATH or environment variable settings?

Perhaps it installs to a standard location, such as
`/bin`, `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`